# Hi I would like to know if there is such getting a global variable in Grails?

Tags: grails

Hi, I would like to know if there is such a thing as getting a global variable in Grails. For example, I would like to get a query in the initial load of the form, then access the data in controllers later on.

Here's my sample code:

```
def SessionFactory
def grailsApplication

def getDepartment(){
    def session = sessionFactory.currentSession
    def query = session.createSQLQuery("SELECT * FROM DEPARTMENT")
    query.setString('UACS_DPT_ID', deptId)
    def result = query.list();

    def departmentList = result
}
```

Then, if I go to a controller, I could simply type:

```
println "LIST:" +  departmentList
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put the result in session like following and use the result later after getting it from session.

```
//save the result in session
session["queryResult"] = departmentList 

// to retrieve the result later just get it from session
def departmentList = session["queryResult"]
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont think thats a good practice. You can hace a bean loaded in the resources with singleton scope and on init load that departments.
The bean can also be injected anywhere you need.